# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'happyfuntokenizing'

Tags: python, import, module, solution

pip install happiestfuntokenizing

After installing the above we get an error on this import function

```
from happyfuntokenizing import Tokenizer as potts

ModuleNotFoundError                      
Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_7944/3774479977.py in <module>
----> 1 from happyfuntokenizing import Tokenizer as potts

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'happyfuntokenizing'
```

I tried looking for the solution but could not find one here....

However try using this and it will work

from happiestfuntokenizing.happiestfuntokenizing import Tokenizer as potts

-Cheers

Answer (score 0):

```py
from happiestfuntokenizing.happiestfuntokenizing import Tokenizer as potts
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).